# How to get current Oracle_SID from command prompt in windows server 2012 R2?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle12c

I use Windows server 2012 with Oracle 12c installed on it. I've configured multiple PDBs in a container and want to know what `ORACLE_SID` is currently in use. Is there any way to identify it from command prompt? or is there other way to identify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

connect

> sqlplus

and type below command,

```
select name,open_mode from v$database;
```

where name represent ORACLE_SID.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways to find SId's. I have used the following.

The Oracle Sid name:  `select instance from v$thread;`

The Oracle Sid number:   `select sid from v$mystat;`